# How do I use this specific selector in HTML

Tags: html, selector

I'm trying to set up an external css file for a page that I'm working on.

In my html file I have a line

```
div id="something"
```

I want to change the color of text in that div, so in my .css file I have a line

```
div #something {color: red;}
```

But the color does not change, I'm just learning and I've spent a bunch of time trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong but I cant figure it out. Any help much appreciated

Comment: ``#something {color: red;}`` should work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the space between the `#` and the id name

So `div#something {color: red;}` should work.

Keep in mind though that since `id`s must be unique in the document, you do not need to specify the tag .

Just `#something {color: red;}` would suffice.

---

Space is use to separate selectors and describes nesting hierarchy (*it is called the [descendant combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator)*).

so `div #something` means target an element with id of `something` that is nested inside a `div`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to link your .css file in your html code! In case you didnt do that...

Do it like this in your `head`.`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fileName.css">`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use :

`div#something {color: red;}`

with no space between `#` and `something` because you're focusing the id element assigned to the div, not an id element assigned on another element into the div, like a paragraph for example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to type this:

```
#something
{
    color:red;
}
```

Show us your css connection in html, it may be done in a wrong way.